# Insertar registro de una tabla a otra mas otro campo

Tags: mysql-workbench

Necesito insertar algunos registros de la tabla 1 a la tabla 2, mas otro registroi nuevo que no esta en la tabla1:

```
Tabla 1
__________
id
nombre
telefono
edad

Tabla2
__________
id
nombre
telefono
edad
direccion
estatus
```

De momento si me inserta los datos pero solo en los campos que coincide, pero no se como modificar para que inserte en campo: "estatus"

```
INSERT INTO tabla2 (id,nombre,telefono)
SELECT id,nombre,telefono FROM tabla1
```

Uso MySQL con Workbench

Comment: ¿Todos deben tener el mismo estatus?

Comment: puede variar: ejemplo, algunos "activo" otros "suspendido" etc

Comment: ¿Y de dónde piensas obtener el estatus de cada id? ¿De otra tabla? ¿Lo introducirás tu manualmente para cada id?

Comment: si perdon me falto el where id='1' en la linea del select

Comment: si se introducirá manualmente depende de la opción seleccionada en la aplicación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es introducir manualmente el valor `estatus`, lo introduces como un literal.

Para todos los registros

```
INSERT INTO tabla2 (id, nombre, telefono, estatus)
SELECT id, nombre, telefono, 'Activo'
FROM tabla1
```

Para un registro concreto

```
INSERT INTO tabla2 (id, nombre, telefono, estatus)
SELECT id, nombre, telefono, 'Activo'
FROM tabla1
WHERE id = 1
```